# Microsoft Service Fabric Stateful Service will not start

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

All of a sudden my local Service Fabric is unable to start Stateful services.
I've tried to uninstall the SDK's, but with no luck. The same service run fine on the Azure cluster.

Even the quickstart service in visual studio won't start

Service Status:
fabric:/testapp/Stateful1 is not ready, 1 partitions remaining.

Service Status:
fabric:/testapp/Stateful1 is not ready, 1 partitions remaining.

Something is taking too long, the application is still not ready.
Finished executing script 'Get-ServiceFabricApplicationStatus'.
Time elapsed: 00:01:41.7659838

---

Error from Service Fabric Explorer: Error event: SourceId='System.FM', Property='State'.
Partition is below target replica or instance count.

Comment: What does your local publish profile and parameters look like? Depending on your routing you need to be careful about having a greater than 1 instance count and services on the same port.

Comment: `<Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="Stateful1_PartitionCount" Value="1" />
    <Parameter Name="Stateful1_MinReplicaSetSize" Value="1" />
    <Parameter Name="Stateful1_TargetReplicaSetSize" Value="1" />
  </Parameters>`

Comment: Do you have any other apps in the cluster or non service fabric applications running in IIS on your machine on the same ports? It might also be worth resetting the cluster via the tray icon, this can sometimes help with inconsistences.

Comment: No other apps in the cluster or in iis. But I noticed that fabric:/System/FaultAnalysisService is in Error state

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are receiving errors about cluster itself and `fabric:/System/FaultAnalysisService`, please look at this [thread](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/15), your issue might be related to lack of disk space.

Assuming you have local cluster setup with default values you can use PowerShell as well to get information about cluster health:

```
# connect to cluster
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint "localhost:19000"
# import commandlets
Import-Module "$ENV:ProgramFiles\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\ServiceFabricSDK.psm1"
# get cluster status 
Get-ServiceFabricClusterHealth
```

I'd recommend using PowerShell to interact with cluster.

Comment: That was it! I only had 9GB available. Seems like 10GB is the minimum to start local cluster. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great. Wish the error message was better. They will need better tools for Service Fabric to estimate and view disk, CPU usage etc. Also, in Azure you can enable Diagnostics and setup Alerts.

Answer (score -1):

Try to disable the symbol server for remote debuging in visual studio.

> Options > Debugging > Symbols > Disable Microsoft Symbol servers

Had the same issue, it turned out that the symbol server returned a 404 when visual studio tried to get the symbols. That slowed down the whole application, so the script thought it failed.

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it did not resolve my issue, as the symbol servers was already turned off.